# Convert omega to frequency in FourierTransform

Tags: fourier-analysis

FourierTransform function in mathematica returns Fourier transform of input function in omega.
[image]

but I need to get Fourier transform of input function in hertz(frequency) that output should be something like this
[image]
However with some changes in FourierParameters and a command like this

```
FourierTransform[1, x, f,   FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

I can't find my desire response.

As I know we can't divide our Fourier output by 2pi because it only amplitude of function not input range as you can see in picture has shown below (as I remember we had to Duality theory to correct our output)
[image]

the maximum should be occur on (their position )/2Pi not in above position

Comment: `FourierTransform[1, x, f, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]/(2 Pi)`

Comment: `FourierTransform[1,x,2*Pi*f,FourierParameters->{1,-1}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is probably this:

```
FourierTransform[((Cos[2 10*Pi*x] Sin[
       2*Pi*x])/(Pi x))^2, x, f, FourierParameters -> {0, -2 Pi}]

(*
==> 1/8 (-22 Sign[-22 + f] + f Sign[-22 + f] + 40 Sign[-20 + f] - 
   2 f Sign[-20 + f] - 18 Sign[-18 + f] + f Sign[-18 + f] - 
   4 Sign[-2 + f] + 2 f Sign[-2 + f] - 4 f Sign[f] + 4 Sign[2 + f] + 
   2 f Sign[2 + f] + 18 Sign[18 + f] + f Sign[18 + f] - 
   40 Sign[20 + f] - 2 f Sign[20 + f] + 22 Sign[22 + f] + 
   f Sign[22 + f])
*)
```

This is in the documentation for [`FourierParameters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierParameters.html).

Comment: Thanks Jens , yes it correct the function argument very well but it doesn't return the proper amplitude for example for Cos[x] it return 2 delta functions with amplitude of Pi , but it should be  2 delta functions with amplitude of 1

Comment: You can adjust the amplitude to anything you want using the first entry in `FourierParameters`. See the docs for `FourierTransform`.